# How to catch complete url in Django view which includes dollar signs?

Tags: python, regex, django, url, path

I've got a simple Django application in which I want to catch the complete url and get some information from it. The url will be of the following form:

```
ourdomain.com/2/abc:AB$12345$AB12345678_01.xyz/abc/1000,1000/1/a.xyz
```

So in my urls.py I catch the url like this:

```
path("<path:the_url>", views.index, name='the_endpoint'),
```

In my unit tests it all works flawlessly. I then tested it manually by doing a call and printing out the url I get in the view:

```
def index(request, the_url):
    print(the_url)
    return HttpResponse("Some response", status=200)
```

But then I get this printed in the terminal:

```
2/abc:AB2345.xyz/abc/1000,1000/1/a.xyz
```

instead of the expected:

```
2/abc:AB$12345$AB12345678_01.xyz/abc/1000,1000/1/a.xyz
```

I removed the dollar signs from the request url, and then I get the url I expect. So the dollar signs are the source of trouble. I'm unsure how I can fix this though.

Does anybody know how I can get the full url when it includes dollar signs?

[EDIT]

I've wrote a simple middleware which I put at the top of the list of middlewares:

```
class SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        print(request.get_full_path())
        print(request.get_full_path_info())
        print(request.get_raw_uri())
        print(request.build_absolute_uri())

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

In it I test whether I can get the raw url before it goes into the other middlewares of the view itself. Unfortunately it also prints out the changed files:

```
/2/abc:edepot:AB2345.xyz/abc/1000,1000/1/a.xyz
/2/abc:AB2345.xyz/abc/1000,1000/1/a.xyz
http://localhost:8000/2/abc:AB2345.xyz/abc/1000,1000/1/a.xyz
http://localhost:8000/2/abc:AB2345.xyz/abc/1000,1000/1/a.xyz
```

So I guess the url is changed earlier on somewhere within Django. Anybody knows where?

Comment: dollar sign in regex is special character so, to specify dollar sign into the path you have to write dollar sign prefixed with a backslash like this: \$

Comment: @abdelhamedabdin - But I want to catch ALL paths, which can include, one or multiple dollar signs. Is that even possible?